# Ajax and browser cache issue

Tags: ajax, sinatra

I have small web site running on Sinatra which is updating content via ajax on a xhr request.

javascript

```
function get_shows() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    url: '/update/',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#show_list').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).html(data).fadeIn('fast');
      });
    }, 
    error:function(data){console.log(data.statusText)}
  });
}
```

ruby

```
get '/update/' do
  if request.xhr?
     erb :index_show_list, :layout => false
  else 
    erb :index  
  end
end
```

The issue I'm having is when a user updates content via ajax, the browser cache for that page updates and only shows the snippet fetched, and all the `head` and `body` tags are gone. The page continues to render ok, until you leave the page and then return via the back back button, in which case all that is displayed is the html snippet sans the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same issue. Try setting cache to false in your ajax request. By default it is set to true.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more info.

Example:

```
function get_shows() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'HTML',
    url: '/update/',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#show_list').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).html(data).fadeIn('fast');
      });
    }, 
    error:function(data){console.log(data.statusText)}
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this, though the issues then is that the back button doesn't work at all. Might have to look into this with History.js. Is there no way to cache the regular page with the updated snippet?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're doing. Why not split out the main page and the updated content? Rather than have them both served by /update/? I'm guessing that your index_show_list.erb doesn't include html/body tags. Is that correct?